# Hamming Distance: unclear logic step involving bitwise operation

Tags: python-3.x, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, hamming-distance

Solving some leetcode question I encountered the hamming distance problem (which I almost forget).

the question was: Given two integers, return the Hamming distance between them.

Now, I know and understand the following logic:

```
def hammingDistance(self, x: int, y: int) -> int:
        x = x ^ y
        distance = 0
        while x:
            if x & 1:
                distance += 1
            x = x // 2
        return distance
```

but if replacing the while loop, with:

```
while x:
    x = x & (x-1)
    distance += 1
```

I don't understand the logic that the AND operation achieving.
It do an AND operation on the XOR operation, and its previous number.
But I dont understand what is the Invariant here.

can someone explain it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your second code snippet, `x & (x-1)` clears the least significant bit that is '1' (not '0') in the binary representation of `x`, i.e. it turns off the rightmost set bit. Each time you perform this operation, you're basically counting and removing the rightmost '1' bit from the binary representation of `x`. Since each bit that is '1' in the XOR result represents a differing bit between `x` and `y`, counting these cleared bits gives you the Hamming distance.

Comment: wow, I should've figure it out. thanks!